# Export excel or csv from html with complex structure table (rowspan or colspan) using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, export-to-excel

I am working on angular project. Now i need to export data to excel in complex table structure. Are there any libraries that can handle this for me?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try below function :

```
function ExportToExcel(fileName)
{
    var isIE = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > 0); 
    if (isIE) {
        // IE > 10
        if (typeof Blob != 'undefined') {
            var fileData = new Blob([document.getElementById("datatable").innerHTML.replace(/="  "/gi, "")], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel,'});
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(fileData, fileName + '.xls');
        }
        // IE < 10
        else {
            myFrame.document.open("text/html", "replace");
            myFrame.document.write(document.getElementById("datatable").innerHTML.replace(/="  "/gi, ""));
            myFrame.document.close();
            myFrame.focus();
            myFrame.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName + '.xls');
        }

    }
    // crome,mozilla
    else {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + document.getElementById("datatable").innerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = uri;
        link.style = "visibility:hidden";
        link.download = fileName + ".xls";
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
}
```

In order to make this function work, in older IE browser you are required to have and **iframe** with name **myFrame**, this is frame is used in this function. Also make sure to wrap your table inside a **div**, in this snippet by div's id is **datatable**

Comment: thanks, let me try this. and I also want it to be base64. could you tell me?

Comment: What you want in base64? Data or Excel sheet?